# How to fix "tf-nightly 2.7.0.dev20210912 requires flatbuffers~=2.0, but you have flatbuffers 1.12 which is incompatible."

Tags: python, tensorflow, flatbuffers

[flatbuffers error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOSE5.png)

can anyone fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`tf-nightly==2.7.0.dev20210912` requires `flatbuffers-2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`.

When you do `pip install tf-nightly==2.7.0.dev20210912`.
It automatically downloads flatbuffers-2.0.